# Как добавить в автозагрузку и как удалить сервис

Tags: centos

Добрый день.

Установил сервис ProFTPd:

```
# yum -y install ncurses-devel gcc gcc-c++ make rpm-build m4 redhat-rpm-config
# cd /tmp/
# wget ftp://ftp.proftpd.org/distrib/source/proftpd-1.3.4a.tar.gz
# tar xzf proftpd-1.3.4a.tar.gz
# cd proftpd-1.3.4a
# ./configure --sysconfdir=/etc
# make
# make install
# cd ..
# rm -fr proftpd*
```

Но не вижу его в автозагрузке chkconfig
Не могу запустить его как сервис:

```
service proftpd start
```

Приходится запускать просто через

```
proftpd
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы он запускался с стартом системы.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить сервис при такой инсталляции в автозагрузку и как удалить (деинсталлировать) его из системы при необходимости?

Comment: Вот еще [статья](https://shneider-host.ru/blog/kak-dobavit-v-avtozagruzku-centos.html) по теме добавления приложений в автозагрузку.

Answer (score 2):

Итак, хэшкод переехал, пожэтому можно писать ответ.

1. Если у вас CentOS до 7 версии

В версиях до 7, использовалась система инициализации init. По сути, это набор шелл скриптов в папке /etc/init.d. Название файла соответствует названию сервиса (их вы и видите в chkconfig). Скрипты простые, по сути они имеют пару-тройку функций (start/stop/restart) и обычно, читают и анализируют pid/lock файлы, чтобы понять запущен сервис и какой его id.
Если вы собираете из исходников, то стартап скриптов, как правило нет (хотя иногда их можно найти в архиве с исходниками).

Ваш выбор либо написать свой скрипт (для этого посмотреть как они устроены анализируя существующие), либо взять из rpm\src.rpm пакета proftpd. Вот для centos5 (но он ничем не отличается от других версий) - http://pastebin.com/Nqwsi3fq

2. Если у вас CentOS 7. Система инициализации теперь systemd. Тут все иначе и в двух словах не объяснить. Стартовые скрипты (name.service) теперь в /usr/lib/systemd/system и имеют вид

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description = ProFTPD FTP Server
> After = network.target nss-lookup.target local-fs.target remote-fs.target
>
> [Service]
> Type = forking
> PIDFile = /run/proftpd/proftpd.pid
> Environment = PROFTPD_OPTIONS=
> EnvironmentFile = -/etc/sysconfig/proftpd
> ExecStart = /usr/sbin/proftpd $PROFTPD_OPTIONS
> ExecReload = /bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy = multi-user.target
> ```

но это тема systemd , читайте тут - http://habrahabr.ru/company/infobox/blog/241237/ :)

К вопросу о том, как удалить собранный из исходников софт. Это зависит от авторов. Если они добавили unstall, то нужно хранить исходники и когда надоест сделать make uninstall в папке с ними.. Вообще исходники крайняя вещь, без особой надобности не стоит так ставить софт.

Answer (score 1):

пробуйте так

```
systemctl start proftpd.service  # просто запуск
systemctl enable proftpd.service # добавить в "автозапуск"
```